# CLI to StackExchange Data Explorer

Tags: command-line-interface, stackexchange-api, data.stackexchange.com

I'm starting to use the [StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), which is a cool tool.

Apart from the [web interface](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new), is there a CLI way to connect to the StackExchange SQL engine without downloading the whole data dump to a local SQL database.

What I want to do is: I want to run a few separate queries in a (shell-)script and save  the result-CSVs in the script automatically to disc.

Comment: The answer is no. What you need to do is create the queries from the web interface, then create a script to log in and download the data.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, Stack Exchange offers an API that covers a lot of REST operations. You can find it and more information on it [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

Comment: Thanks, but that is not exactly what I'm after. I rather want to kick off my queries from a CLI tool. I guess I can build a CLI tool using the REST API myself though.

Comment: I believe that's the only way, since I never heard of a project like that before. Perhaps you can make it open-source and others can contribute ;)